# Generics and selecting correct interface implementation at runtime

Tags: java, generics

I'm working on a PoC of an ES & CQRS system.

I have defined following classes to represent commands and events that represent an output of command being handled

```
public class CreateEstateCommand extends Command {}

public class ChangeEstateOwnerCommand extends Command {}

public class EstateCreatedEvent extends DomainEvent {}

public class EstateOwnerChangedEvent extends DomainEvent {}
```

The commands are being handled in classes that implement the following interface

```
/**
 * Specific command handlers define what logic should be carried out during handling a command of type C.
 * Single command execution results in an outcome of domain event of type E
 */
public interface CommandHandler<C extends Command, E extends DomainEvent> {
  E handleCommand(C command);
}

public class EstateCreatedCommandHandler implements CommandHandler<CreateEstateCommand, EstateCreatedEvent> {
    @Override
    public EstateCreatedEvent handleCommand(CreateEstateCommand command) { /***/ }
}

public class ChangeEstateOwnerCommandHandler implements CommandHandler<ChangeEstateOwnerCommand, EstateOwnerChangedEvent> {
    @Override
    public EstateOwnerChangedEvent handleCommand(ChangeEstateOwnerCommand command) { /***/ }
}
```

Now there's the part where I want to use those specific handlers. The flow of command handling can be represented as follows:

Command gets into the system through the API, and they are forwarded to `CommandServce` class for handling

```
public class CommandService {

    private final EventService eventService;
    private final CommandGateway commandGateway;

    public void handleCommand(CreateEstateCommand command) {
        EstateCreatedEvent event = commandGateway.handleCommand(command);
        eventService.handleEvent(event);
    }

    public void handleCommand(ChangeEstateOwnerCommand command) {
        EstateOwnerChangedEvent event = commandGateway.handleCommand(command);
        eventService.handleEvent(event);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `handleCommand()` methods are duplicated for each of the command submitted. The reason behind this is the problem I have with selecting appropriate handler implementation at runtime, depending on `Command.commandType`:

```
@Service
public class CommandGateway {

    private final Map<String, CommandHandler<?, ?>> commandHandlers;

    @Autowired
    public CommandGateway(Map<String, CommandHandler<?, ?>> commandHandlers) {
        this.commandHandlers = commandHandlers;
    }

    public EstateCreatedEvent handleCommand(CreateEstateCommand command) {
        EstateCreatedCommandHandler handler = (EstateCreatedCommandHandler) commandHandlers.get(command.getCommandType());
        return handler.handleCommand(command);
    }


    public EstateOwnerChangedEvent handleCommand(ChangeEstateOwnerCommand command) {
        ChangeEstateOwnerCommandHandler handler = (ChangeEstateOwnerCommandHandler) commandHandlers.get(command.getCommandType());
        return handler.handleCommand(command);
    }

}
```

The snippet above is the part I cannot generify. Is it possible, to implement `CommandGateway` class, so `CommandService` can look as follows:

```
public class CommandService {
    
    public <C extends Command, E extends DomainEvent> void handleCommand(C command) {
        E event = commandGateway.handleCommand(command);
    }
}
```

And provide type-safe objects?

Comment: The "provide type-safe objects" part I'm pretty sure is no.  Generics are a compile time only construct, they go away at runtime.  And since your lookup happens at runtime, there's no way for generics to be involved.  You'll need some runtime information for that.  Look for Joshua Block's "Type Safe Heterogeneous Container" pattern for ideas.

Answer (score 1):

The root problem is the map, whose values are wildcard typed, ie effectively untyped, and more particularly, not typed to align with the key.

You've already ripped up some typed safety by trusting the injected map's entries, so just take it one step further by using a raw `CommandHandler`, which will accept any command, and use an unchecked cast for a properly typed return value:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
public <C extends Command, E extends DomainEvent> E handleCommand(C command) {
    CommandHandler handler =  commandHandlers.get(command.getCommandType());
    return (E)handler.handleCommand(command);
}
```

`@SuppressWarnings` added so neither your IDE nor build complain.

While this might seem brutal, you haven't actually lost any type safety. That was lost when you typed your map as you did, which unfortunately was unavoidable given that map typing does not bind the value type to the key type.

Comment: "You've already ripped up some typed safety by trusting the injected map's entries" - the map is used here only because of convenient spring autowiring of such beans - there are no particular arguments behind using it.
Do you have any other idea that do not involve maps of such type and would be a better fit in this scenario??

Comment: @bwylegly I have been in similar situations a few times myself. Unfortunately, there's no solution that avoids a cast *somewhere*. Take the simple example of `Map<Class<?>, Object>>` where I *know* that the value object is an instance of the class key, but there's no way to type the map so I can just code `MyClass obj = map.get(MyClass.class);`. You can create a wrapper class with a map field that achieves this, but that just moves the unchecked cast inside the wrapper class. An unchecked cast has to go somewhere - you should chose the place you're most comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

What if you do something like this:

```
static abstract class Command {

    public abstract String getCommandType();

    public abstract Class<? extends DomainEvent> type();
}
```

And your implementation:

```
public class CreateEstateCommand extends Command {
    @Override
    public String getCommandType() {
        return null; // whatever here
    }

    @Override
    public Class<EstateCreatedEvent> type() {
        return EstateCreatedEvent.class;
    }
}
```

And usage would be:

```
public DomainEvent handleCommand(Command command) {
    return command.type().cast(commandHandlers.get(command.getCommandType()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty in achieving this end-to-end with generics is that we are mixing **runtime type decisions** with **compile-time type checks**. You design is close to an MVC design, where handlers are retrieved at runtime. So, only limited type-safety checks are possible at compile-time.

Let us look at a flow:

- An API recieves a command with its inputs
- You may have a specific controller method that knows the command and its inputs and can construct one of `CreateEstateCommand` or `ChangeEstateOwnerCommand`
- Now, **at runtime** we have to access the map to know the associated `CommandHandler`. Now, the very reason we have to do this at runtime is because the decision cannot be made at compile time, due to the design of using a `Map`.

If you have the following method in `CommandGateway`, it can never be sure if the `Command` instance passed from the service class is really the **specific child** that the mapped `CommandHandler` wants. Hence, it will not compile.

```java
public DomainEvent handleCommand( Command command ) {
    CommandHandler<? extends Command, ? extends DomainEvent> cmdHandler = commandHandlers.get(command.getCommandType());
    return cmdHandler.handleCommand( command );
}
```

Hence, you have to do away with either the end-to-end type safety requirement or with the "factory" style map that gives you the `CommandHandler` instance. Leaving out the latter will mean that the API method, right in the beginning, knows which `CommandHandler` it needs.